# Handling fragment menus options

Tags: android, menu, android-fragments

I have two fragments, one a ListView and one a "details" view.  Each fragment has it's own menu options.  When in landscape mode, where both fragments are displayed, each menu is merged into one (which, I'm assuming is by design), but if I rotate the device to portrait, the menus remain merged, and show options that shouldn't be there.  Not sure if I need to include any code in my question.

Edit:

Found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472776/fragments-with-the-same-menu-on-the-same-layout-cause-duplicated-menuitem), but adding menu.clear() only shows the menu options for the details view, when in landscape and changing back to portrait, the menu doesn't change.

I guess the bigger question is how to do you handle fragments, each with the own set of menu options.

Update:

To be clear, the menus work fine if the device is left in portrait or landscape mode.  The issue occurs when rotating from landscape to portrait or vice versa.  The menus do not seem to reset even though `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out this issue, if you are using `setRetainInstance(true)` then the menus will not refresh.  Unfortunately, removing this break other things such as my AsyncTask is killed when changing orientation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new on here so apologies if I don't format everything in top-notch. I too have had similar questions regarding menu contributions and `Fragment`s. Here is what I did in my instance...

I have a `FragmentActivity` hosting a `ListFragment` and an additional `Fragment` containing details of the list item selected- pretty typical tablet config. This additional detail `Fragment` is not added until a list item is selected... When I select a list item I want to prevent the `ListFragment`s menu items from contributing to the hosting `FragmentActivity` Action Bar. (From a UI perspective the users main focus is the newly added Fragment, to return to the previous state they deselect the item they selected.) Since the `ListFragment` should not know about the other Fragment to ensure re-usability I found that leveraging the `onPrepareOptionsMenu(..)` method at the `FragmentActivity` level was the correct way forward for me.

Add this snippet of code to the hosting `FragmentActivity` to quickly get the behaviour you want;

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
   // 'Find' the menu items that should not be displayed - each Fragment's menu has been contributed at this point. 
   menu.findItem(id.sync).setVisible(false);
 }
return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

This method means that your Fragments remain reusable (they are still contributing as initially designed) but your host `FragmentActivity` can manipulate the Activity UI which is one of it's authorised roles.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to refresh the inflated menus to the action bar every time the orientation change try to declare that your activity in the manifest holding the fragments to listen in configuration change

Then override the method onConfigurationChanged, and use the invalidateOptionMenu API
see this link:

Activity invalidate options menu:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29

If this helps you, please mark this post as an answer.

Thanks.