# Why do I get copies of the same option menu item in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I use ActionbarSherlock together with Fragments. In one of the Fragments I add an option menu item in the Actionbar. It shows up and when I click it I get a callback in which I move to another Activity. When I return to this Activity I get another copy of the same option menu item in the Actionbar. I know have two option that I can press. Both works.
How do I get rid of the extra menu item?

The menu looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_scan_book"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/menu_scan_book"/>
</menu>
```

In my SherlockFragment I have this code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.scan_book_action_menu, menu);
}
```

In the SherlockFragmentActivity owning the Fragment I have tried to call

> supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()

when I return from the Activity I moved to above.

What am I missing?

Comment: If I had to guess, you have two action bar items because you have two copies of the fragment, somehow.

Comment: Maybe, but I have to check that more. I get several copies of the option item the longer I keep the app open and do things. I will check this up with multiple copies of the fragment.

Comment: Problem disappered after a restart of Eclipse. It was probably a build problem. Sorry for taking up your time.

Comment: Restarting Eclipse certainly fixes a lot of problems, though to be honest I never would have expected it to help in this case. Glad to hear it is working for you, though!

Comment: You were right. It did not help. An option item is added every time i tap on it. I call another intent (scan with bar code scanner) and then returen to this activity. I am anat over the weekend but ned to debug more when I returen.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call `menu.clear()` in `public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` ? It's just a workaround but it worked for me.

Go here for more informations : [Fragments, with the same menu, on the same layout cause duplicated menuitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472776/fragments-with-the-same-menu-on-the-same-layout-cause-duplicated-menuitem/8495697#8495697)